# Does the Wii Sport Kit improve your control?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers

I found a sports kit with the following:

- Steering wheel
- Tennis Racket
- Golf club
- Baseball bat
- Cricket bat

Do any of these improve your control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will not make the controller sense the proper movements more accurately.

They exist to either make the motions easier to visualize (a-la steering wheel) or provide a larger area for gripping the controller in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think it just give you right feeling. And maybe help you to hold controller better (if you never played e.g. golf). But, as I noticed in most games, it doesn't matter that much how well you move your hand (tennis, golf, etc).

Answer (score 1):

They don't really improve your control much.  What they do however, is help with the feeling of immersion.